# Loading Images with .click() even handler

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to attempt trying to have an AJAX-like situation where I load an image in a  tag when a button is clicked. However, there will be only 2 buttons (prev & next) and a text-input option where it would contain the image name the user desires to have loaded. Currently, I am just bearing fruit from having read a bunch of books from O'Reilly (on PHP, MySQL, jQuery, JS). And as of right now, I know that I have a few options to begin research in to create this script. But, I was hoping that I could get a few pointers as to where the learning curve is the least steep.

If I went the PHP root, I know I could use GET or POST methods to discern the prev and next images, but I wouldn't be able to use jQuery from within PHP will I?

And then, I know I could just go the JS/jQuery route where I could just do some regex to grab the digits within a filename when a button is pressed to discern the prev/next image. But, I wasn't sure if I could just insert an img within a div tag without AJAX even if I do use jQuery?

In this light, which would be quicker to pursue a deeper understanding of to develop this project? Is there another route I'm not aware of into which you recommend I delve?

Comment: You don't load images with Ajax. You can load *the markup* for the image (a tag, `<img src="...">`), and inject it into a div. You can also create a "tag" from jQuery (actually, an "Element"), no need for Ajax or php.

Comment: This doesn't sound to me like you need to use AJAX at all for this.  Simply load up the images using jQuery if you ask me.  Doesn't make sense using PHP `$_POST` or `$_GET` to accomplish this.  A bit too extreme for just changing images prev and/or next IMO. AJAX would be useful if you needed to grab and/or put information into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest pursuing a 'single-page-app' type approach, because that's the direction I would go, and it won't be any more difficult than any other method.  Learning things right is never easy, but it's worth it.

In short I would do this:

1. I would hookup a POST route in your server code that takes the text provided by the user as a parameter. If you haven't written any server side code yet, use a framework. Laravel and Symfony are good ones to start with. (This route should either return an image or an error message if it's not found? ...not sure what you had in mind)
2. Write some simple jquery that handles the onclick event of the button, grabs the text from the text box, and then makes an ajax call to the POST route mentioned above.
3. The ajax call's callback will then handle the image or error message you get back from the server and update the DOM accordingly.

This way, you won't have to get an entirely new page from the server, and you can just update small things as necessary. This seems like a good simple thing to start with. Good luck!